# ¿Cómo colocar menú a la izquierda e inicio de sesión a la derecha en barra de navegación?

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy intentando que mi barra de navegación cuente con las opciones a la izquierda e "iniciar sesion" esté a la derecha.

He probado con *float*, *margin*, *padding* pero no logro hacerlo. También he probado creando un **id** para los botones y asi trabajar con ellos individualmente pero me descuadra el **nav**.

Se que es mucho código pero he estado pensando que el error puede estar en la estructura html quizás.

```css
/*Configuracion general de pagina*/
*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}
/*Barra de Navegacion*/
nav{
    background: #8bc34a;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.enlace{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 50px;
}

.logo{
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;

}

nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

#sesion{
    background: #00bcd4;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: #dcedc8 solid 5px;
    
}

/*Hovers de Barra de Navegacion*/
.logo:hover{
    border: #00bcd4 solid 2px;
    transition: .2s;
}

#sesion:hover{
    color: #00bcd4;
    background: #dcedc8;
    border: #00bcd4 solid 5px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.boton:hover{
    color: #00bcd4;
    transition: .5s;
}

/*Cosas que dejo pre hechas para funcionalidades de mas adelante uwu*/
.checkbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#check{
    display: none;
}

/*Seccion de contenido*/
section{
    background: url(fondo.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

section{
    background: url(img/junta-propietarios-imgEs20200901012745.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: calc(100vh - 30px - 80px);
}

/*Footer*/
footer{
    background: #757575;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.texto{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 7px 20px;
}

#instituto{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <!--MetaDatos, Titulo y Conecciones(Librerias)-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="Index_meh.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Papaya | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Navegacion-->
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
        <a href="#" class="enlace"><img src="img/images.jpg" class="logo" alt="No se encuentra imagen"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="boton" href="#">Quienes Somos</a></li>
            <li><a class="boton" href="#">Galeria</a></li>
            <li><a class="boton" href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            <li><a id="sesion" href="#">Iniciar Sesion</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--Contenido-->
    <section></section>
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
        <p class="texto">Cesar Aros | Andres Nuñez | Mario Mora</p>
        <p class="texto" id="instituto">Instituto Santo Tomas | Informatica</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Debajo del HTML, no supe como dividir el codigo en dos partes asi que le puso un **ESTO ES MI CSS**

Comment: Ok, perdona, no me fijé bien. Bueno, he arreglado un poco la pregunta para que sea mejor aceptada por la comunidad. A ver si alguien te ayuda (particularmente prefiero usar bootstrap que CSS puro, por lo tanto no podria ayudarte con certeza, lo siento). Suerte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```css
/*Configuracion general de pagina*/
*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

header{
    width: 100%;display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    background: #8bc34a;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

nav > ul{
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

.btn{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    background: #00bcd4;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: #dcedc8 solid 5px;
}

.logo{
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#sesion{
    background: #00bcd4;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: #dcedc8 solid 5px;
    
}

/*Hovers de Barra de Navegacion*/
.logo:hover{
    border: #00bcd4 solid 2px;
    transition: .2s;
}

#sesion:hover{
    color: #00bcd4;
    background: #dcedc8;
    border: #00bcd4 solid 5px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.boton:hover{
    color: #00bcd4;
    transition: .5s;
}

/*Cosas que dejo pre hechas para funcionalidades de mas adelante uwu*/
.checkbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#check{
    display: none;
}

/*Seccion de contenido*/
section{
    background: url(fondo.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

section{
    background: url(img/junta-propietarios-imgEs20200901012745.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: calc(100vh - 30px - 80px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <!--MetaDatos, Titulo y Conecciones(Librerias)-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Papaya | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
            <a href="#" class="enlace"><img src="http://tulogo.cat/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/TuLogo300ppp.jpg" class="logo" alt="No se encuentra imagen"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="boton" href="#">Quienes Somos</a></li>
                <li><a class="boton" href="#">Galeria</a></li>
                <li><a class="boton" href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <button class="btn">INICIAR SESIÓN</button>
    </header>
    <!--Contenido-->
    <section></section>
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
        <p class="texto">Cesar Aros | Andres Nuñez | Mario Mora</p>
        <p class="texto" id="instituto">Instituto Santo Tomas | Informatica</p>
    </footer>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Lo que hacemos es crear una etiqueta `header`, (vamos a trabajar con flexbox), dentro de ese `header`, tenemos el nav (con la imagen de logo y el menú) y además un `button` (muy importante qué esté fuera del `nav`). Aplicamos `display:flex` al `header`para que ponga en línea el nav con el botón de iniciar sesión, y un `justify-content: space-between` para que coloque a un extremo de la pantalla los elementos, es decir, en la parte izquierda va a poner el nav y en la parte derecha al botón. Además, aplicamos `display:flex` al `nav` (para qué ponga los elementos en línea, en este caso la imagen y la botonera, y aplicamos de vuelta `flex` a la `ul`, para que ponga en línea también la botonera. Para más información sobre flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: Muchas gracias te pasaste, ahora mismo voy a investigar el flexbox y algunas cosas mas, te agradesco muchisimo

Comment: De nada, cualquier otra pregunta estoy a la orden. ¡Saludos!